# How to use Rails mailer settings when creating a custom Mail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, actionmailer

I'm creating a `Mail` object in a Rails app and want it to pick the mailer settings:

```
original = UserMailer.new_registration
original.deliver# Does the job

custom = Mail.new(original.to_s)
custom.deliver # Fails: OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: hostname does not match the server certificate
```

Apparently the custom `Mail` object isn't picking up the Rails settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/delivery_methods.rb), we can pick up the config from the mailer the following way:

```
custom = ::Mail.new(raw_email)
key = Rails.application.config.action_mailer.delivery_method
delivery_method = ActionMailer::Base.delivery_methods.fetch(key)
delivery_settings = ActionMailer::Base.send("#{key}_settings")
custom.delivery_method(delivery_method, delivery_settings)
custom.deliver
```

Comment: Thank you. Been pounding my head on this one.

Answer (score 0):

To send custom mails using rails please read this.

http://mdushyanth.wordpress.com/2011/08/06/custom-mail-delivery-method-in-rails-3/

Comment: So how do you pick the Rails configured settings?

Comment: what? The `environment.rb` has no settings whatsoever. Those are in either `application.rb` or one of the `environment/<RAILS_ENV>.rb`. So how do you tell `Mail` object to deliver using those settings??